# Which point on the object does pose refer to in roboearth detector?

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the re_kinect_object_detector for detecting objects that have been modeled using the re_object_recorder. I was able to get the pose of the object being detected ([Pose of the object in Roboearth](http://answers.ros.org/question/2439/pose-of-the-object-in-roboearth)). However, I was unable to find out in the documentation about which point on the object does the pose return. For example, if we use the videogame cover as the object, during detection there are multiple points on the object that is highlighted as red indicating that these have been detected. But which point does the pose correspond to? This is important because the object itself will take several units in the x,y,z axis, so knowing exactly which point the object is located will help me to track the object pass its information for other modules.

I am using ROS Electric on Ubunto 11.04. Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12186/which-point-on-the-object-does-pose-refer-to-in-roboearth-detector?/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The origin of the object coordinate system is at the center of the marker pattern when the object was recorded. The red points are just the object model drawn into the image.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2011-12-07**:
Please note that the pose estimation is not completely stable. Thus, you will notice small "jumps" in the detected object pose.

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-12-07**:
Thanks. But if I place the videogame cover vertically as opposed to horizontally I seem to get different poses. Doesn't this go against the fact that both the placements have the same origin?